# Controlling child entity from master table in JPA

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0

let say I have the below entities

```
@Entity
public class Item{

    private Country origin;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="origin")
    public Country getOrigin() {
        return this.origin;
    }

}

@Entity
public class Country{

    private String code;
    private String desc;

    @Id
    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    @Column
    public String getDesc() {
        return this.desc;
    }

}
```

where `Country` class is mapped to a preset master table and should not be modified.
Users are able to set the `origin`'s `code` when creating new `Item`.
How can I check if the provided `code` is already an entry in the master table?

If I simply `persist()` a new `Item` with a non exsisting `code` without persist the child, a `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException` will be reported. Do I just need to try-catch this exception to treat it as non-existing master data? Or is there any better alternatives?

In real case there are a lot of these child entities in the `Item` object, I think it's not a good idea to explicitly look up the master data one by one. And I think this is not a good solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Any solution will require a look up to the master table to see if the `Country` already exists or not. It's a question of whether you make this call explicitly, or you ask your framework (Hibernate) to do this for you.

I would be explicit and validate the `Country` data against the table if you know the source/input that is creating the `Item` cannot be relied on. If you have a GUI that you have tight control over, then perhaps this error will never occur because you should be giving the user only the valid options that do exist. Also by being explicit, you can write your Unit tests to include this explicit check if you know that you must check before persisting because of unreliable data.

Keep in mind that Hibernate will cache your queries to the Country table, so I wouldn't expect it to affect the performance of your application.